# Integral of "f" from -A to A implies "f "is an odd function

Tags: calculus, integration

Let A$\in{\mathbb{R}}$, ***f*** a continous function in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\int_{-A}^{A} f=0$, then ***f*** is an odd function.

I've tried splitting the integral at x=0 and substituted x=-t, but I don't really get anywhere. Any help would be greatly appriciated.

(It's not a HW question, but has been on a previous exam and I'm practicing for my upcoming exam)

Comment: This is not quite correctly stated. You need to assume that the property holds for *all* $A \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\int_{-x}^x f(t)dt.
$$

Comment: Please write elaborately so that I can understand.

Comment: @rama_ran : Do you know and understand the fundamental theorem of calculus?